# Override view: website_sign/static/src/xml/website_sign_common.xml

Tags: xml, odoo-11

I have tried to change the view by extending it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <div t-extend="website_sign.thank_you_dialog">
        <div t-jquery=".row o_promote_esign" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="row o_promote_esign">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="/website_sign/static/description/icon.png" alt="Document Sign" class="img img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h4>Do you also send documents to sign?</h4>
                It's easy, incredibly efficient and totally free: you just have to create an account.
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</templates>
```

But it is not working. Any suggestion what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are in the right way.
After extending the view you have to load the template file from js like following:

```
    odoo.define('module_nm.js_nm', function (require) {
       'use strict';

        var core = require('web.core');
        var ajax = require('web.ajax');
        var qweb = core.qweb;
        var test = require('base_module_js_nm');

        test.include({   
           _loadTemplates: function(){                                
             return $.when(this._super(), 
           ajax.loadXML('/module_nm/static/src/xml/file_nm.xml', qweb))         
            },          
       });
    });
```

Then, you have to add this js file in an assets.xml file like the following:

```
<template id="tmpl_id" inherit_id="web.assets_frontend" name="Template name">        
    <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">            
          <script type="text/javascript" 
                src="/module_nm/static/src/js/js_file_nm.js"></script>            
    </xpath>
</template>
```

May this work. Thank you.